# Rectangles and gaps between then.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

First of all, I'm not from the fields of mathematic. So I beg your patience and comprehension on my lack of background on describing this problem. Consider we have the following problem:

We have an N number of rectangles evenly spaced. They have a width called C. The gap between each rectangle is called G. The horizontal distance between the left extreme of the first rectangle to the right extreme of the last rectangle is called W.

Now consider a variable P which when set to 0.5 makes the rectangle's individual widths equals to any gap (all gaps are equal). The variable P may be from 0.0 to 1.0 and it defines balance between rectangle width and gap width. The W is always fixed.

What would be the mathematical formula for obtaining C by knowing W, P and N?

Comment: if we assume that the gap is not null or negative, when the rectangle width increases, W must increase by the unitary increment of one rectangle ( 2 halves , right and left ). But you said that W is constant. Then there is another effect

Comment: yeah, W is the distance where the rectangles are sorted on

Comment: Would I be correct assuming that this is essentially a 1d problem? You are talking about rectangles, but apparently all that matters is their width, so I take it that you only arrange the rectangles in a single horizontal row, not in a grid or similar as I had assumed when I started reading. You might want to edit that in. The role of $P$ is still somewhat unclear. You give the meaning of $P=0.5$, and state the range, but I'm unsure about the intended behavior at the extremes. Would $P=0$ mean zero rectange width, all gaps, and $P=1$ mean zero gap and touching rectangles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the total width? It is the width of $N$ rectangles plus the width of $(N-1)$ gaps:

$$W = N\cdot C + (N - 1)\cdot G = N\cdot P\cdot X + (N-1)(1-P)X$$

where $X=C+G$ is the length of periodicity, i.e. the distance from the left edge of one rectangle to the left edge of the next. This combined length I divide according to $P$: If $P=0.5$ I divide it evenly, so that rectangle and gap have equal length. If $P=0$ all the width is in the gaps, and if $P=1$ all the width is in the rectangles. In general you have $C=P\cdot X$ and $G=(1-P)\cdot X$.

Now solve the above for $X$:

$$X=\frac{W}{N\cdot P + (N-1)(1-P)}$$

or since you asked to derive $C$ use

$$C=P\cdot X=\frac{P\cdot W}{N\cdot P + (N-1)(1-P)}$$